# Alternate way for DataContext Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm

in mvvm pattern we encapsulate viewmodel in to view and exposing it as DataContext and doing binding for controls

Is there another way than this type of binding (without calling the DataContext)

pls let me clear regarding this

Thanks in advance

Comment: MVVM is _generally_ the best pattern to follow for WPF... can you explain your situation so we could suggest something relevant? You can bind to statics, any dependency property, or even just set the data members manually.

Comment: Thanks Cory for replying ,i am just asking the alternate way than calling the datacontext in usercontrol.Now i am using the format as follows  like we have a viewmodel class called productviewmodel and we are exposing this in view like <usercontrol.resources><local:viewmodel x:key="viewcontext"/></usercontrol.resource> then <grid x:name="gridmain" DataContext="{Binding Source=(StaticResource viewcontext}}"> then <Textbox text="{Binding productName}"/> <button command="{Binding submitprocess}"/>

Comment: Set the datacontext and not resources. Like this: <usercontrol.datacontext><local:viewmodel/></usercontrol.datacontext>

Comment: If you're trying to avoid the DC you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to set any `DataContext` properties to connect views to view models. You can just set up a number of `DataTemplate`s instead:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:FirstViewModel}">
    <Views:FirstView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Views:MainView />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:LastViewModel}">
    <Views:LastView />
</DataTemplate>
```

If you declare these in the `App.xaml` file, they will be available throughout your application.